# How to fix it, what a missing in my script

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this script

when I test in Postman i have notice like this

how to fix it? thq

---

I have this script

```
<?php

//creating response array
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//getting values
$teamName = $_POST['name'];
$memberCount = $_POST['member'];


//including the db operation file
require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

$db = new DbOperation();

//inserting values
if($db->createTeam($teamName,$memberCount)){
    $response['error']=false;
    $response['message']='Team added successfully';
}else{

    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='Could not add team';
}

}else{
$response['error']=true;
$response['message']='You are not authorized';
}
echo json_encode($response);

<?
```

when I test in Postman i have notice like this

```
<br/>
<b>Notice</b>: name in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebService\api\createteam.php</b> on line
<b>11</b>
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: member in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebService\api\createteam.php</b> on line
<b>12</b>
<br />
{"error":true,"message":"Could not add team"}
```

how to fix it? thq

Answer (score 0):

> Undefined index: member

```
$memberCount = $_POST['member'];
```

You are missing a "member" value in your expected POST data

I recommend checking if values exist before using them.

```
if (!isset($_POST['member'])) {
    throw new Exception("missing expected value \"member\" in POST");
}
$memberCount = $_POST['member'];
```

Comment: Could you mark it then, otherwise other users won't know that your problem is solved